Migrate from IdentityServer4 to openiddict and use static lients list in code without accesing DB
I need help. I want to migrate from IdentityServer4 to Openiddict. I have a custom table for accounts and the login I was able to migrate them. My problem is that I have clients stored as static in code with some logic, how can I use them without the need to access db?  I have this code:
public interface ICustomClientStore
{
    IEnumerable<CustomClient> GetClients();

}
public class CustomClientStore : ICustomClientStore
{
    protected List<string> ConfigureRedirectURIs()
    {
        var clientTrustedURIs = TrustedInternalURIs.URIS_CLIENT_SWAGGER_DEV;

        Func<string, List<string>> createRedirectUri = (string s) =>
        {
            return new List<string> {
                // DEFAULT
                String.Format("{0}/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html", s),
                
                // TIP: this is for new Swagger
                String.Format("{0}/help/oauth2-redirect.html", s),
                String.Format("{0}/help-internal/oauth2-redirect.html", s),
                //String.Format("{0}/oauth2-redirect.html", s),
            };
        };
        return clientTrustedURIs.SelectMany(str => createRedirectUri(str)).ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<CustomClient> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<CustomClient>
    {
        new CustomClient
        {
            Type = "public",
            ClientId = "SWAGGER-ADMIN",
            DisplayName = "Standard - Swagger Client",
            Permissions = new List<string>
            {
                OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
                OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
                OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
                OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Profile,
                OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Email,
               "openid",

                ApiResources.CoreWebAPI_Admin.API_NAME
            },
            AllowedResponseTypes = new List<string>
            {
        OpenIddictConstants.ResponseTypes.Code,
        OpenIddictConstants.ResponseTypes.IdToken
            },
            RedirectUris = ConfigureRedirectURIs()


        }
    };
    }
} 

and my registration
services.AddOpenIddict()
          .AddCore(options =>
          {
              options.SetDefaultApplicationEntity<CustomClient>(); // Set a dummy entity type to disable application store
              options.SetDefaultScopeEntity<CustomScope>();

              options.AddApplicationStore<CustomApplicationStore>();
              options.AddScopeStore<NoOpScopeStore>();
          })
          .AddServer(options =>
          {
              // Enable the token and authorization endpoints.
              options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();

              // Enable the authorization and token endpoints
              options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                     .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");

              options.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ValidateTokenRequestContext>(builder =>
              {
                  builder.UseSingletonHandler<CustomTokenRequestValidator>();
              });

              options.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext>(builder =>
              {
                  builder.UseSingletonHandler<ValidateGrantTypePermissionsHandler>();
              });

              // Register the encryption and signing credentials.
              options.AddEphemeralEncryptionKey()
                     .AddEphemeralSigningKey()
                     .DisableAccessTokenEncryption();

              // Manually validate clients via event handlers
              //options.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleAuthorizationRequestContext>(builder =>
              //{
              //    builder.UseSingletonHandler<CustomClientValidator>();
              //});

            

              // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
              options.UseAspNetCore()
                     .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                     .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough();
          });

If I don't add something in the core part I have an exception that I need a store, so I create a dummy store where I return the results from my static list. After that, I wanted to use the handlers but even when I implemented and registred they were not called to be able to validate the authorize and token call. What I do wrong?
As i describe my problem i created dummy store but not able to be able to access my hadlers for validation
